# How to force python requests module to use higher TLS versions without modifying code

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, openssl

I am trying to use a 3rd party python package which connects to an API server. The API server is still offering TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 and only offering insecure cipher suites.

The python package uses the `requests` module with no additional configuration around TLS version restrictions or cipher suites. When the module tries to connect to the API server, it first tries TLSv1 and because the cipher suites don't match I get an `SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING` error from the package. I've already confirmed this is, in fact, because it is trying to negotiate TLSv1 first and not matching ciphers.

My question is, how do I force Python, or more specifically the `requests` module, to negotiate higher protocols first? I've tried setting the `openssl.cnf` option for `MinProtocol = TLSv1.2` but this did not make any difference. I do not want to modify the code for the package - this is a 3rd party package. This needs to be done with environment settings somehow.

This seems like a completely backwards implementation of SSL. Why in the world would it start negotiating the lowest protocol first and move up? It should be the other way around.

Comment: I can't believe that. TLS negotiation does not 'first' try one then another standardly, and certainly not in OpenSSL _or_ Python; rather ClientHello offers a range of versions (specifying a maximum but not minimum up to 1.2, or a list with 1.3) from which the server selects. The last version of OpenSSL that started negotiating at v1.0 was in 2012, and very few systems today are that old. Please show exactly what you 'confirmed'. Show the CH if possible. Also determine the version of OpenSSL used (with Python, may differ from commandline) because that can matter.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes, you're right. After digging in further, I identified that Wireshark was showing TLSv1 in the outer client hello message, but the client was offering TLSv1.2 in the inner message. I discovered the API server had it's cipher suite tweaked incorrectly and for some reason and even with hundreds of people accessing this thing, only Python seemed to not be able to pair up the cipher suites available. We've since corrected the cipher suite issue on the server. Thanks for your attention to this.